# selecting a radiobutton opens new form with selected image

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, picturebox

I have a winform c# app in which the user can select from various `RadioButton`s with an `ImageBox` next to them.
What I wish to do is, when a `RadioButton`is selected the same image appears on another form to continue the process.
Basically what I need is to transport the selected image from `picturebox1` in `formA` to a `picturebox2` in `formB`.

What I have now is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        build build = new build(); 
        build.ShowDialog();
    }  
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
```

...

This only opens the form `build` which has the `PictureBox` in with I want to load the same image from `formA`.

Thanks for the support,

EDIT:

I tried the solution by Mong Zhu but nothing happens when i click the button. How do i indicate the picturebox where i want the picture to display? My code is:

FormA:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        build build = new build (@"/Images/2C.png");
```

FormB:

```
public partial class build : Form
{
    string img = @"/Images/2C.png";
    public build(string img)
    {
        img = @"/Images/2C.png";
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Once again many thanks for the help, So i used your code but now i get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in xxxx.exe
>    Additional information: Object reference not set as an object instance.

EDIT 3:

Ok, So, thanks your tips the code advances but now I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Invalid characters on path. In the line:

```
pictureBox2.Load(img_from_A);
```

I guess this is because of the path i used, the images are stored in the bin\Images folder of the project and they are added to the solution explorer.

The code i use is:

```
 build build = new build("@|DataDirectory|/Images/JAF.jpg");
```

I also tried:

```
build build = new build("@../Images/JAF.jpg");
```

and

```
build build = new build("@/Images/JAF.jpg");
```

Same error. Any sugestions And thanks again.

Comment: how is your picturebox called in FormB / build?

Comment: I edited my answer with the code you gave me

Comment: in which line you get this exception? Apparently you forgot to instantiate some object that you are trying to use

Comment: the line is:
`pictureBox2.Load(img_from_A);`

Comment: You probably executed the line before the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor. check my second edit.

Comment: up to now you basically already posted 3 Questions. If you would have posted them separately you could have gained reputation to get closer to the ability to communicate in a chat or write comments.

Comment: I edit my answer for the third time. Have a look. ps. since I answered you 3 Questions by now, you could have at least accept the answer ;)

Comment: you are welcome. Ask more questions -> get more reputation -> then you can write comments and use the chat ;)

Comment: Just a follow up question, i tried to do the same thing but to get the value from a label in FormA to a textbox in Form B, but i get the error:
_Build does not contain a contructor that takes 2 arguments_.
The code i used is the following:
formA  
`public build(string img_from_A)  
         {  
             InitializeComponent();            
             pictureBox2.Load(img_from_A); 
             larg.Text = label1.Text;`
formB  
`build build = new build("@../Images/JAF.jpg","label1.text");`

Comment: if you change the constructor call in formB : `build build = new build("@../Images/JAF.jpg","label1.text");` you also have to change the constructor! At the moment it takes only 1 string as argument: `public build(string img_from_A)`, you need to at a second parameter in the contructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically need is a field in `FormB` like:

```
string image_path;
```

you can then rewrite the constructor and pass this path to the form when you call it in `FormA`:

```
FormB formB = new FormB(image_path_from_formA);
```

the constructor would initialize the field then:

```
public FormB(string image_path_from_somewhere)
{
    image_path = image_path_from_somewhere;
}
```

now you can use this path to load the image into the `PictureBox` of `FormB`

**EDIT:**

I will try to use your code:

FormA:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        build build = new build (@"/Images/2C.png");
    }
}
```

In FormB you can either store the path for later use or load the picture right away:

```
public partial class build : Form
{
    // you don't need to initialize it. You will pass the right link
    // later through the constructor
    string img;

    public build(string img_from_A)
    {
        // store for later use
        img = img_from_A;

        // or load it right away
        pictureBox1.Load(img_from_A);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Please make sure that you try to access any element in the constructor **AFTER** the `InitializeComponent()` call:

```
public partial class build : Form
{
    // you don't need to initialize it. You will pass the right link
    // later through the constructor
    string img;

    public build(string img_from_A)
    {
        // First this has to happen!
        InitializeComponent();


        // store for later use
        img = img_from_A;

        // or load it right away
        pictureBox1.Load(img_from_A);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

if you are using windows and your image is in `bin\Images` folder you should use a back-slash \ instead of / and use this line:

```
build build = new build("@..\Images\JAF.jpg");
```